# Certain font weight not rendering for local machine

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a webpage that uses Google fonts and refers to the font as such:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">`

Calling specific weights had no changed effect either. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600,400">`

As per the screenshot below I don't have Open Sans installed on my local machine.
[image]

Looking through the web inspector you can see I have 400 as the set font-weight. As I transition from 200 all the way up to 600 you see that only after typing in 600 the font changes to the appropriate weight (600):

[image]

I double checked this problem by having a colleague checking the same page by having him compiling it on his computer. He was able to render the correct font-weight.

My font wasn't rendering even though I have it correctly referenced.

Comment: Give google fonts link with (https:\\www.font.google.......)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution. If you use any conflicting font versions with the Typekit Font Sync integration with any Adobe products you will need to disable the font within your Typekit account.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the differents weights you want to use:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: forgot to mention that method had no effect as just calling Open Sans itself defaults to the 400 weight which is what I wanted.